# MySQL insertion into database table with lots of columns (using jdbc)

Tags: mysql, json, jdbc, insert, sql-insert

I have a table with 10 columns. Each row in the table was is originally a JSON Object that I receive in this format.

```
{"mainEntity":
    "atlasId": 1234567
    "calculatedGeography": False
    "calculatedIndustry" : False
    "geography": "G:6J"
    "isPublic" = False
    "name" = XYZ, Inc
    "permId" = 12345678987
     primaryRic=""
     type=corporation
}
```

I am using jdbc and a mysql driver. The problem is my insert statements look very long and ugly(see example below) because of the high number of columns. Is there a way to solve this or is this the only way. Also, is there a way to insert multiple records at the same time with jdbc?

```
"INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(1234567, False, False, "G:6J", False, "XYZ, Inc", 12345678987, "", corporation"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you only wondering about style or also performance? always use prepared statements when you make inserts, this will unclutter your code and make sure the datatypes are all correct.

If it is about speed, you might try transactions, or even "load data infile". The load data method requires you to make a temporary CSV file that is directly loader into the database.

Comment: Thank you, i wasn't even aware of something called a PreparedStatement, now my code is much neater!